# Haystack capturar excepción 'QueryParserError'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Cuando realizo una peticion con: ?q=---%20+++ usando Hystack, me lanza la siguiente excepción 'QueryParserError'.

error en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trace del error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.99.100:8000/search/?q=---%20+++

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('app',
 'userprofile',
 'common',
 'place',
 'course',
 'venture',
 'task',
 'activity',
 'advertisement',
 'communication',
 'enrollment',
 'canvas',
 'reporting',
 'localapi',
 'campaign',
 'grappelli.dashboard',
 'grappelli',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'axes',
 'constance',
 'crispy_forms',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_jenkins',
 'location_field',
 'django_extensions',
 'djcelery',
 'friendship',
 'haystack',
 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
 'rest_framework',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'storages',
 'celery_haystack',
 'compressor')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/views.py" in __call__
  53.         return self.create_response()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/views.py" in create_response
  133.         (paginator, page) = self.build_page()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/views.py" in build_page
  110.         self.results[start_offset:start_offset + self.results_per_page]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in __getitem__
  272.                 self._fill_cache(start, bound)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/query.py" in _fill_cache
  171.         results = self.query.get_results(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in get_results
  645.                 self.run(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in run
  557.         final_query = self.build_query()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xapian_backend.py" in build_query
  1250.             query = self._query_from_search_node(self.query_filter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xapian_backend.py" in _query_from_search_node
  1291.                 constructed_query_list = self._query_from_term(term, field_name, filter_type, is_not)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xapian_backend.py" in _query_from_term
  1313.             return [self.backend.parse_query(query)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xapian_backend.py" in parse_query
  844.         return qp.parse_query(query_string, self.flags)

Exception Type: QueryParserError at /search/
Exception Value: Syntax: <expression> NOT <expression>
```

la vista usada es: `from haystack.views import SearchView`
y su url es:

```
url(
    r'^search/$',
    SearchView(),
    name='search',
),
```

Alguien sabe como capturar esta excepción?

Comment: Cuando eso sucede se debe mandar un error 500, error de servidor, no un 404, lo que necesitas es validar la entrada.

Puedes poner todo el código relacionado con el error?

Comment: ¿Que parte del código necesitas? dado que la vista que tiene esa url es: from haystack.views import SearchView.

Comment: La parte final, contiene la lìnea final que da el error, normalmente, y puedes revisar las variables que estàn dando el error.

Comment: Listo hombre te deje todo el trace

Comment: Como es el query que intentas entrar?

Comment: este: `?q=---%20+++`

Comment: pero en tu formulario o lo que sea que reciba esa entrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar actualizando django-hystack y cambiando de xapian a whoosh, actualizando Python a 3.5 y actualizando Django a 1.8.13, mis versiones son:

- whoosh==2.7.4
- django-haystack==2.4.1

Comment: Entonces el problema es como manejaban las `query` anteriores versiones de `haystack`.

Comment: @SalahAdDin aparentemente.